# How to pass the soap XML in a Gatling script

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, performance-testing, gatling

I'm Trying to create a Web services script in Gatling , but i'm not sure how do i pass the XML soap in the script. From the Gatling documentation learned that we need to send the xml through .body(StringBody(), but mot sure of the format.

This is the XML , which i need to pass

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <p359:DeleteSellSeqReq xmlns:p977="http:xxxxx.com" xmlns:p619="http://xxxxx.com" xmlns:p359="http://xxxxx.com/2006/11/15/MaintainSellSequence_1">
            <p977:RequestContextBean xmlns:p357="http://xxxxxx.com">
                <p357:RequestTransactionID>xxxxxxxxx</p357:RequestTransactionID>
                <p357:FlowSeqNum>1</p357:FlowSeqNum>
                <p357:ContextFrames>
                    <p357:Name>xxx</p357:Name>
                    <p357:Type>xxx</p357:Type>
                    <p357:ServiceInterface>com.sxxxxxxxxxxx</p357:ServiceInterface>
                    <p357:Operation>buildRequestContext</p357:Operation>
                    <p357:IPAddress>xxxxxxx</p357:IPAddress>
                <p357:LocalContextParameters>CTX_UTC=1493024853726</p357:LocalContextParameters>
                    <p357:LocalContextParameters>VERSION=Unknown Version</p357:LocalContextParameters>
                </p357:ContextFrames>
                <p357:ContextFrames>
                    <p357:Name>NodeName</p357:Name>
                    <p357:Type>NodeType</p357:Type>
                    <p357:ServiceInterface>xxxxxxxxxxxxx.businessServices.SellSequenceService.SellSequencePort</p357:ServiceInterface>
                    <p357:Operation>deleteSellSequence</p357:Operation>
                    <p357:IPAddress>localhost</p357:IPAddress>
                    <p357:LocalContextParameters>CTX_UTC=1493024853728</p357:LocalContextParameters>
                    <p357:LocalContextParameters>VERSION=1</p357:LocalContextParameters>
                </p357:ContextFrames>
            </p977:RequestContextBean>
            <p619:Channel>xxx</p619:Channel>
            <p619:Division>xxx</p619:Division>
            <p619:RateCode>xxx</p619:RateCode>
            <p619:ChainCode>xxx</p619:ChainCode>
            <p619:AfflCd>xxx</p619:AfflCd>
        </p359:DeleteSellSeqReq>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is the best way to do it, but as a simple demonstration:

```
val someBody = "<soapenv:Env..."
val someRequest = http("some name")
                      .post("some route")
                      .body(StringBody(someBody))
val sc = scenario("some scenario")
             .exec(someRequest)
```

If this doesn't answer your question, then be more specific about what exactly you're having trouble with.